# Why host stops when halting LXC guest?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualization, lxc

I'm following these directions to create an LXC box on Debian 7 (wheezy):
http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2013/07/18/crafting-your-own-vagrant-lxc-base-box/

I start a container/guest using this command:

```
sudo lxc-start -n wheezy-base
```

But when I halt it, the host stops as well.

```
sudo halt
```

What am I doing wrong? How to stop an LXC guest correctly and get back to the host?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Debian 7, and don't have access to LXC user namespaces (which *should* be available in jessie, and *are* available in stretch). So, "root" in a container is equivalent to root on the host. Thus when you call `sudo halt` you are doing so as root for the whole system.

(Containers on such older systems are not secure and cannot be made secure; you should be using a newer version of Debian, or preferably a Red Hat-based system, for any container work that requires even a moderate amount of security.)

To kill a container, from outside the container use `lxc-stop`.

```
lxc-stop -n wheezy-base -k
```

From inside the container, try `kill -PWR 1` to fake the container's init process into thinking the (nonexistent) power button has been pressed.